# Stop an SKPhysicsBody mid-motion

Tags: swift, skspritenode, momentum

If an SKSpriteNode has had an impulse applied to its SKPhysicsBody so that it now has momentum, is there a way I can get it to immediately stop moving? Applying an equal and opposite impulse would probably work in theory, but I would like to know if there is a simpler way. Thanks (:

Comment: Did you try `body.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)`?

Comment: I didn't think about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set its velocity to zero:

```
body.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
```

You might also want to set its angular velocity to zero:

```
body.angularVelocity = 0
```

And if you want it to become immune to forces and impulses, turn off `dynamic`:

```
body.dynamic = false
```